# trying to use a closure with parameters as a callback

Tags: javascript

I have a library function that I'm calling from a method. It takes a callback with one parameter that I would like to be another method from the same object.  I can't seem to get the syntax right.  Here's what I've got:

```
myOriginalObject.login = function() {
    // inside a method
    var obj = this;
    var closure = function(token) { return function() { obj._login2(token); } }
    $window.gapi.auth.authorize({"client_id": this.clientId,
                                 "immediate":false,
                                 "response_type":"token",
                                 "scope":this.scopes}, closure );       

    // .. some more code and method ends
}
myOriginalObject._login2 = function(authResult)
{
  // .. I can't get this function called by the gapi library
}
```

P.S. sorry if this post isn't done properly (still learning) thanks!!!

Comment: yes but. . . yep that led me to the solution.  Thank you very much.  I just passed in myOriginalObjct._login2 and that worked.  I thought that since it was part of a factory (in angularJS) that I couldn't do that but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a reference to the `closure` function to `authorize`, but I think you want to *call* it and pass the reference to the function it creates. So:

```
// `token` argument here ------------------v
var closure = function() { return function(token) { obj._login2(token); } }
// not here------------^
```

and

```
$window.gapi.auth.authorize({"client_id": this.clientId,
                             "immediate":false,
                             "response_type":"token",
                             "scope":this.scopes}, closure() );
// Call it -----------------------------------------------^^
```

---

You may not need the `closure` function at all, but it's hard to tell without knowing more about the surrounding code. But this may well be all you need:

```
$window.gapi.auth.authorize({"client_id": this.clientId,
                             "immediate":false,
                             "response_type":"token",
                             "scope":this.scopes}, function(token) {
                                 obj._login2(token);
                             });
```

---

Side note: Since `myOriginalObject` is a singleton, you don't need the `var obj = this;`, you can just use the symbol `myOriginalObject` directly:

```
$window.gapi.auth.authorize({"client_id": this.clientId,
                             "immediate":false,
                             "response_type":"token",
                             "scope":this.scopes}, function(token) {
                                 myOriginalObject._login2(token);
                             });
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

`var closure = function(token) { return function() { obj._login2(token); } }`

will return a function, i.e. the return value of closure() is a function.

One solution:

change

```
var closure = function(token) { return function() { obj._login2(token); } }
```

to

```
var closure = function(token) { obj._login2(token); }
```